# Redirect all subdirectory pages to new domain home page in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I like to redirect all pages under **olddomain.com/subdirectory/** to be redirected to **newdomain.com**?

The newdomain.com site has a new URL structure, so I want every page under the **olddomain.com/subdirectory/urls** to be redirected to the **newdomain.com** homepage.

I tried below code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^olddomain.com/subdirectory/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But its redirecting with existing url like `http://newdomain.com//url` and its through 404 error.

Any help highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If anyone has problems with this code, try putting it at the TOP of your .htaccess file. That's what worked for me.